# How to properly configure averageUtilization of hpa in k8s

Tags: kubernetes-hpa

This is the configuration information about resources and HPA of my helm application, as follows:

```yaml
resources:
  limits:
    cpu: 2
    memory: 4096Mi
  requests:
    cpu: 0.5
    memory: 1024Mi

autoscalig:
  enabled: true
  minReplicas: 4
  maxReplicas: 8
  targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 320
  targetMemoryUtilizationPercentage: 320
```

Can anyone tell me how the value of `targetCPUUtilizationPercentage` or `targetMemoryUtilizationPercentage` is calculated?